# C# Filtering number on datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

I have a one `textbox`, one `combobox` and one `datagridview` and datagridview have some data on it.Combobox carry information about datagridview coloumn name.When I write text on textbox datagridview will be filtered according to column name which is in combobox.The code is given is not working when I try to write number on textbox It gave me error something like

> 'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Double and System.String.'.

What I must do here for work.

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] like '%{1}%'", combobox.Text, textBox1.Text);

(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reasonable. You cannot apply the LIKE SQL operator to numbers.

You could fix this like below:

```
double number;
string rowFilter = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out number) ?   
    string.Format("[{0}]='{1}'", combobox.Text, textBox1.Text) :
    string.Format("[{0}] like '%{1}%'", combobox.Text, textBox1.Text);
```

The method `TryParse` of double is used when we want from parsing a string to create a double. If this is possible, the string is the string representation of a double, then the method performs the conversion and returns `true`. The converted number is stored in out variable. While when the conversion fails, it returns `false`. Given that and using the ternary operator, `?`, we can create the correct filter in all cases.

Comment: How can I filter number on datagridview?There must be a solution

Comment: Now this gave me this error "The expression contains an invalid string constant: '."

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz oops, I have forgotten an apostrophe `'`. Please see my updated code and let me know. Thank  you.

Comment: Is there a way to filter starting with the number I want to filter.For example I want to filter this numbers=127085452 When I write 127 on textbox I want to see my filtered results (In this method I must write all numbers to filter)

Comment: Of course it can be done. But it's a bit more difficult than the filtering you apply now. You should do some googling and reading before trying this. I suggest you start searching for real time searching gridview. Furthermore, you should keep in mind that in this case you will write client side code.